# skeletonization using OpenCV in c#

Tags: c#, opencv

does anyone have an example of how to skeletonization using OpenCV in C #.

thank you

Comment: -1. Google will help you with this kind of questions. Questions here are expected to include some research effort. What have you tried? What are problems you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, i don't have example from C#. But I can give you a method using OpenCV-Python. It is done with basic OpenCV functions, so all functions I used should be available in C# also.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png',0)
size = np.size(img)
skeleton = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
finished = False

while(not finished):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img,kernel)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,kernel)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skeleton,temp)
    img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros==size:
        finished = True

cv2.imshow("skeleton",skeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is the result:

[image] [image]

Method is not so good, so result also not perfect. But better, i hope.

EmguCV documentation : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/Index.html

I am sure all functions will be available there. So implement yourself.